# Can a bot who's a member of a group track the amount of messages sent?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to track the number of messages sent in a group, which my bot was invited to, without having to disable Privacy Mode. Just Count.

I'm currently using node-telegram-bot-api.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## **No.**

The [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots#privacy-mode) is quite clear about this

> A bot running in privacy mode will not receive all messages that
>   people send to the group. Instead, it will only receive:
>
> - Messages that start with a slash ‘/’
> - Replies to the bot's own messages
> - Service messages (people added or removed from the group, etc.)
> - Messages from channels where it's a member

So if a message does not fulfill those conditions your bot will not receive the update at all.